# failed to edit the data, but if I don't input the image it will work fine

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

## Controller

Here I delete the old image then add a new image, I have followed the lines of code on the internet but I feel something is wrong

```
    public function update(Request $request, Article $article)
    {
        $request->validate([
            "title" => "required|string|max:255",
            "body" => "required",
            "category_id" => "required",
            "is_active" => "required",
        ]);

        if ($request->file("image") == "") {
            $article->update([
                "title" => $request->title,
                "slug" => Str::slug($request->title),
                "body" => $request->body,
                "category_id" => $request->category_id,
                "user_id" => Auth::id(),
                "is_active" => $request->is_active,
                "views" => 0,
            ]);
        } else {
            Storage::disk("local")->delete("public/article/" . $article->image);
            $image = $request->file("image");
            $image->storeAs("public/article", $image->hashName());
            $article->update([
                "title" => $request->title,
                "slug" => Str::slug($request->title),
                "body" => $request->body,
                "category_id" => $request->category_id,
                "user_id" => Auth::id(),
                "image" => $image->hashName(),
                "is_active" => $request->is_active,
                "views" => 0,
            ]);
        }

        return redirect(route("article.index"))->with("success", "Data Updated Successfully");
    }
```

## Views

I modified this line of code from Laravel's bootcamp page. Previously I had made a simple crud without images and it worked

```
import React from "react";
import AuthenticatedLayout from "@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout";
import InputError from "@/Components/InputError";
import PrimaryButton from "@/Components/PrimaryButton";
import { useForm, Head } from "@inertiajs/inertia-react";

export default function Edit({ auth, categories, article }) {
    const { data, setData, put, processing, reset, errors } = useForm({
        title: article.title,
        body: article.body,
        category_id: article.category_id,
        image: null,
        is_active: article.is_active,
    });

    const submit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        put(route("article.update", article.id)), { onSuccess: () => reset() };
    };

    return (
        <AuthenticatedLayout
            auth={auth}
            header={
                <h2 className="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
                    Article Edit: {article.title}
                </h2>
            }
        >
            <Head title="Article Edit" />

            <div className="px-20 py-10">
                <form onSubmit={submit}>
                    <label htmlFor="" className="font-semibold text-lg">
                        Title
                    </label>
                    <input
                        name="title"
                        type="text"
                        value={data.title}
                        className="px-3 py-1 mt-1 mb-5 block w-full border-gray-300 focus:border-slate-900 focus:ring-slate-900 rounded-md shadow-sm"
                        onChange={(e) => setData("title", e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="" className="font-semibold text-lg">
                        Body
                    </label>
                    <textarea
                        name="body"
                        id=""
                        rows="10"
                        className="block mt-1 mb-5 rounded-md shadow-sm border-gray-300 focus:border-slate-900 focus:ring-slate-900 w-full"
                        value={data.body}
                        onChange={(e) => setData("body", e.target.value)}
                    ></textarea>
                    <label htmlFor="" className="font-semibold text-lg">
                        Category
                    </label>
                    <select
                        name="category_id"
                        id=""
                        className="block mt-1 mb-5 rounded-md shadow-sm border-gray-300 focus:border-slate-900 focus:ring-slate-900 w-full"
                        onChange={(e) => setData("category_id", e.target.value)}
                    >
                        {categories.map((category) =>
                            category.id == article.category_id ? (
                                <option value={category.id} selected>
                                    {category.category_name}
                                </option>
                            ) : (
                                <option value={category.id}>
                                    {category.category_name}
                                </option>
                            )
                        )}
                    </select>
                    <label htmlFor="" className="font-semibold text-lg">
                        Image
                    </label>
                    <input
                        onChange={(e) => setData("image", e.target.files[0])}
                        type="file"
                        name=""
                        id=""
                        className="block mt-1 mb-1 w-full text-sm text-slate-500
                        file:mr-4 file:py-2 file:px-4
                        file:rounded-md file:border-0
                        file:text-sm file:font-semibold
                        file:bg-gray-500 file:text-slate-50 file:cursor-pointer
                    "
                    />
                    <img
                        src={"/storage/article/" + article.image}
                        alt=""
                        className="w-52 mb-5"
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="" className="font-semibold text-lg">
                        Status
                    </label>
                    <select
                        name="is_active"
                        id=""
                        className="block mt-1 mb-5 rounded-md shadow-sm border-gray-300 focus:border-slate-900 focus:ring-slate-900 w-full"
                        onChange={(e) => setData("is_active", e.target.value)}
                    >
                        {article.is_active == 1 ? (
                            <>
                                <option value={1} selected>
                                    Publish
                                </option>
                                <option value={2}>Draf</option>
                            </>
                        ) : (
                            <>
                                <option value={1}>Publish</option>
                                <option value={2} selected>
                                    Draf
                                </option>
                            </>
                        )}
                    </select>
                    <InputError message={errors.title} className="mt-2" />
                    <InputError message={errors.body} className="mt-2" />
                    <InputError message={errors.category_id} className="mt-2" />
                    <InputError message={errors.image} className="mt-2" />
                    <InputError message={errors.is_active} className="mt-2" />
                    <PrimaryButton className="mt-4" processing={processing}>
                        Save
                    </PrimaryButton>
                </form>
            </div>
        </AuthenticatedLayout>
    );
}
```

## if i include a image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uorCv.png)

## if I don't include a image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UZYC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Inertia Docs](https://inertiajs.com/file-uploads)

> Uploading files using a multipart/form-data request is not natively supported in some languages for the put,patch or delete methods. The workaround here is to simply upload files using post instead.

So instead of using `put()` when sending an update you can use the `post()` then add the a new attribute that contains the appropriate request method.

```
Inertia.post(route('article.update', article.id), {
  _method: 'put',
  // your other attributes here
})
```

Comment: wow this worked, thanks sir. so i can modify my code to be like this
`code`
    const { data, setData, post, processing, reset, errors } = useForm({
        title: article.title,
        body: article.body,
        category_id: article.category_id,
        image: null,
        is_active: article.is_active,
        _method: "put",
    });
`code`
`code`
    const submit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        post(route("article.update", article.id)), { onSuccess: () => reset() };
    };
`code`